# How can I pass additional parameters to a FUN when I'm already using the elipsis?

Tags: r

I have a function like this for retrieving items.

```
fetchItem <- function(name, ..., FUN)
```

- **name**: string of the filename
- **...**: zero to many parts of path or url etc that it builds the full path behind the scenes (without going into too much detail this is very important for the consumers that they can throw whatever at it and it just 'does it all for them')
- **FUN**: [optional] to define a 'reader' function for how you want to read it (different reader functions for JSON vs CSV etc that process and return it how they want it).

So far so good, this works well. But now I have a request where they want to be able to pass additional parameters to the FUN reader (basically options like if it has a header row, if it uses a funky delimiter of some kind that kinda thing, there are a bunch of them they want to support). The reader will be able to handle these additional parameters if I can figure out how to pass them through this but I'm new to R and struggling with the syntax of how this chains together.

Comment: Could you add a `FUN_args` argument to `fetchItem`, which contains any additional arguments to `FUN`? You'd then need to parse `FUN_args` to extract relevant arguments for `FUN`.

Comment: @ Maurits Evers I think that would probably work but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to just pass those thru to whatever FUN resolves to

Comment: An alternative would be to parse all additional arguments and then decide ad-hoc whether to pass an argument to `FUN` or not. This wouldn't be too difficult I imagine, provided you have a list of allowed arguments for `FUN` against which you can match.

Comment: snappymcsnap, do one of the answers address your question?

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the point from my last comment above, how about something like this?

```
do_something <- function(x, ..., FUN = NULL) {
    if (is.null(FUN)) print(x)

    # Get all additional arguments
    args <- list(...)

    # Match additional arguments that are allowed for FUN
    args_for_FUN <- NULL
    if (length(args) > 0) {
        allowed_args_for_FUN = c("na.rm")

        # Allow for partial matching
        names(args) <- sapply(names(args), function(arg)
            match.arg(arg, allowed_args_for_FUN))
        args_for_FUN <- args[names(args) %in% allowed_args_for_FUN]

    }

    # Execute FUN (if given)
    if (is.function(FUN)) do.call(FUN, c(list(x = x), args_for_FUN))
}
```

Let's do some test cases:

```
# Case 1: No FUN, no additional args
do_something(1:10)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

# Case 2: With FUN, no additional args
do_something(1:10, FUN = mean)
#[1] 5.5

# Case 3: With FUN, no additional args
do_something(c(1:10, NA), FUN = mean)
#[1] NA

# Case 4: With FUN, with an additional arg for FUN
do_something(c(1:10, NA), na.rm = T, FUN = mean)
#[1] 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I *can* conceive of times that this might be problematic, one technique could be to use all unnamed arguments for the one purpose, and require all `FUN` arguments be explicitly named.

Over-simplifying that your use of `...` is simply to concatenate into a file path:

```r
fetchItem <- function(name, ..., FUN) {
  dots <- list(...)
  nms <- names(dots)
  args1 <- is.null(nms) | nms == ""
  list(
    nofunargs = c(name = name, dots[args1]),
    funargs = dots[!args1]
  )
}
str( fetchItem("foo", "bar", FUN = read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE) )
# List of 2
#  $ nofunargs:List of 2
#   ..$ name: chr "foo"
#   ..$     : chr "bar"
#  $ funargs  :List of 2
#   ..$ stringsAsFactors: logi FALSE
#   ..$ header          : logi TRUE
```

---

Another alternative is a little fragile: arguments *after* `FUN=` (must be named) are passed to `FUN`, not to the first purpose.

```r
fetchItem2 <- function(name, ..., FUN) {
  args <- as.list(sys.call())[-1]
  nms <- names(args)
  FUNind <- which(nms == "FUN")
  if (!length(FUNind)) FUNind <- length(nms) + 1L
  list(
    nofunargs = args[ seq_len(FUNind - 1L) ],
    funargs = args[ -seq_len(FUNind) ]
  )  
}
str( fetchItem2("foo", "bar", FUN = read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, name = "othername") )
# List of 2
#  $ nofunargs:List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "foo"
#   ..$ : chr "bar"
#  $ funargs  :List of 3
#   ..$ stringsAsFactors: logi FALSE
#   ..$ header          : logi TRUE
#   ..$ name            : chr "othername"
```